# useStyles not working as it should in mui5?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to custom style my icon adding a bigger font size, the background is working fine but the font size is not, I read that I can use important! but I want to know why it is not working as it has been working in version 4 .

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: 140,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
     '&:hover': {
       backgroundColor: 'red',
   },
  },
}));

 <Box style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
     <EmojiObjectsIcon color='primary' className={classes.icon} onClick={switchTheme} />
 </Box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add px for fontSize like this :

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
          root: {
            flexGrow: 1,
          },
          icon: {
            fontSize: '140px',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
             '&:hover': {
               backgroundColor: 'red',
           },
          },
        })); 
    
        
    
       const PublicSidebar = () => {
            const classes = useStyles();
    
      return (
              <Box style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <EmojiObjectsIcon color='primary' className={classes.icon} onClick={switchTheme} />
               </Box>
            )
            }
```

Comment: Hi, I have a problem , the icon gets smaller …. It worked only once. I don’t want to use important.